# Why is Saudi Arabia extending US$5.5 billion to Pakistan?

Tags: pakistan, saudi-arabia

- [Saudi Arabia comes to Pakistan’s rescue with $1 billion assistance](https://en.dailypakistan.com.pk/headline/saudi-arabia-comes-to-pakistans-rescue-with-1billion-assistance/)
- [Saudi-backed bank to grant loan to Pakistan](https://www.firstpost.com/world/saudi-backed-bank-to-grant-loan-to-pakistan-india-must-realise-limits-of-weaning-riyadh-away-from-islamabad-4949281.html)
- [KSA interested in heavy investment in Pakistan](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1780812/1-ksa-interested-heavy-investment-pakistan-crown-prince-tells-imran/)

What is Saudi Arabia's motivation to fund Pakistan?

**Note.** I am searching for a neutral narrative.

Comment: Who funds all the madrassas there? Doesn't seem to be a new thing. https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/saudi/analyses/madrassas.html

Comment: No, this loan seems to aid the government. My point is that it's not something new for Saudis to send funds to Pakistan, one way or another.

Comment: At this point any answer would be speculative. But there are a few traditional reasons. Both Iran and Saudi Arabia have, in the past, used Pakistan in their proxy wars. My guess is that this new capital loan has some strings attached. Also Pakistan is in no conditions to refuse. It will probably accept funding from both SA, China, and the IMF (unless the US interferes).

Comment: Yes. It appears both in the [Iran-Pakistan relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Pakistan_relations), and the [Iran-Saudi Arabia Proxy conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran–Saudi_Arabia_proxy_conflict) articles in wikipedia. The last accusation was just a few months ago due to Iran recruiting of Pakistani Shia to fight in the conflicts they are involved. This has been reported in mainstream media like [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-44280552). You also have an article about the [Zainab Brigade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liwa_Zainebiyoun) on wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you expect me to say. Both Iran and Saudi Arabia have conducted operations with state and non-state actors in Pakistan in order to achieve their objectives in their proxy wars. Saying that the state of Pakistan is directly involved or not is speculative because for decades it has tried to maintain a semblance of neutrality. But it seems clear that there are factions in Pakistan that are pro-Iran and that is no accident. This is even more serious if you consider the current Fragile State Index of Pakistan. As of now it is considered an unreliable actor at best.

Comment: The FSI is a measure of the vulnerability of a state to conflict, unrest, etc. It is usually associated with low international credibility and lack of harmony between different factions of the country. The implication was that saying the Pakistani government didn't officially said this or that isn't really saying much, as there might be other actors intervening. But you seem to be clearly emotionally involved with this subject and I feel it's for the best to remove myself from this conversation. I hope you get the answers you are looking for. Best regards.

Comment: The $5.5B in the title is, I believe, misleading. From the articles it looks like $1B in aid (with more being sought) and $4.5B FDI. Given the historically close relationship between the two countries and Pakistan's current debt issues, what makes this seem out of the ordinary?

Comment: While the question is good and the answer is good, I thought I've heard asking why a person do something is off topic because we can't read people's mind

Answer (score 5):

It's not too terribly complicated.

1. India's economy is growing more rapidly than Pakistan's, which risks Pakistan's economy.
2. Saudi Arabia and Pakistan are both Sunni nations, while Iran is Shia.
3. Pakistan shares a border with Iran.
4. Saudi Arabia's biggest fear is that Iran make it back to the world stage and start regaining power via the EU relaxing sanctions on Iran.
5. Saudi Arabia's biggest asset is money.
6. Therefore, Saudi Arabia is investing in Pakistan so that if they're ever forced to go to war with Iran, Pakistan will allow Saudi Arabia to land troops on Iran's border with Pakistan.

Comment: I would also add that the US has historically been supportive of this relationship since the 1980s. See Chapter 3 of the [documentary](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/frontline/film/bitter-rivals-iran-and-saudi-arabia/transcript/) *Bitter Rivals: Iran and Saudi Arabia*.