# Is the U.S. (really) Vying for Dominance in Pakistan?

Tags: united-states, china, pakistan

Take a look at this: [Why China and the U.S. Are Vying for Dominance in Pakistan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVYdqoVJIeI)

Also, from **3:32** of the video:

> ... one way it (the USA) could do this is to influence IMF to place terms on the bail out such as specific restrictions from borrowing from China. This would force Pakistan to significantly roll back belt and road projects.

which is not true as Pakistan is sourcing its money from other place like [Saudi Arabia](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1805691/1-economy-high-agenda-pm-imran-visits-saudi-arabia-today/).

So,

Firstly, If they are both vying for dominance in Pakistan, why is the [USA spliced with India](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/first-22-dialogue-defining-moment-for-indo-us-relations-mattis/article24932058.ece)?

Secondly, why would Pakistan be tempted to abandon China while the USA is spliced with India?

Comment: "What if" is always hard to answer, but maybe asking yourself whether the Saudis would do anything that goes directly against the interests of the US could produce some productive ideas.

Comment: @janh, https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33004/why-is-saudi-arabia-extending-us5-5-billion-to-pakistan

Comment: US achieved dominance in Pakistan decades ago. We have supported their military dictatorship, funded their weapons, we used their airbases during the Afghanistan war. Except the madrasas, which are funded by the Saudi's.

Comment: @JamieClinton, `US achieved dominance in Pakistan decades ago.` --- except, China wasn't a $15 trillion economy and India was a USSR-ally back then.